# How to convert into refined type?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, http4s, refined

I am using the library https://github.com/fthomas/refined and would like to convert `java.util.UUID` to refined's `Uuid`.
How to convert `java.util.UUID` to refined's `Uuid`?

**Update**

I have the following http routes:

```
  private val httpRoutes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of[F] {
    case GET -> Root / UUIDVar(id) =>
      program.read(id)
```

and the read function is defined as follows:

```
  def read(id: Uuid): F[User] =
    query
      .read(id)
      .flatMap {
        case Some(user) =>
          Applicative[F].pure(user)
        case None =>
          ApplicativeError[F, UserError].raiseError[User](UserNotRegistered)
      }
```

The compiler complains:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.util.UUID
[error]  required: eu.timepit.refined.string.Uuid
[error]       program.read(id)
[error]         

       ^
```

Comment: Refined's `Uuid` is used to check than a **String** contains a valid `UUID` so you can be safe if you convert that string into a real UUID, why do you need the opposite?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Probably **zero_coding** prefers to keep a guarantee that a string is a valid uuid not inside data type `java.util.UUID` but inside refined type `String Refined Uuid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is transformation `java.util.UUID` into `eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined[String, eu.timepit.refined.string.Uuid]`

```
import java.util.UUID    
import eu.timepit.refined.string.Uuid
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined

val uuid: UUID = UUID.fromString("deea44c7-a180-4898-9527-58db0ed34683")

val uuid1: String Refined Uuid = Refined.unsafeApply[String, Uuid](uuid.toString)
```

Comment: How can I use it related my example with `UUIDVar(id)`?

Comment: @zero_coding Let's start with your signature. `def read(id: Uuid)...` is strange. `eu.timepit.refined.string.Uuid` is a predicate, not data type. Data types are `java.util.UUID`, `String` or `Refined[String, Uuid]` (aka `String Refined Uuid`). Where did you get signature `def read(id: Uuid)...`? Should it be `def read(id: String Refined Uuid)...`?

Comment: Where can I find the tutorial about refined? I thought that `Uuid` is a type.

Comment: @zero_coding it's a type, but it's predicate, not string refined with predicate.

Comment: @zero_coding For example at the very beginning of the tutorial it's written `val i1: Int Refined Positive = 5`. You do not write `val i1: Positive = 5`.

Comment: @zero_coding So if correct signature is `def read(id: String Refined Uuid): F[User]` then  you can do `program.read(Refined.unsafeApply[String, Uuid](id.toString))`.